# Axios.all: How do I use a thesaurus API to allow my search bar to include synonyms of the input word in its search results?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

I have a searchbar for for a job listing site that I am trying to give the ability to pull up related words (example: if someone searched for 'web development' but a job was listed under 'software engineering' it would still be returned).

I am using axios to simultaneously get job info from my database, and get synonyms of the inputted word from a 3rd party API.  I want to have it check for synonyms, then return job listings that match all synonyms of the inputted word.

As of right now, I have methods that set info returned from the database to state as answer1 or answer2 depending on whether the user chose to search by company or job title.  My first instinct was to set the info from the synonym API as 'answer3' on the state object, but I can't figure out where in the method I need to tell it to return jobs that match all synonyms of the input as well.  This is what I have so far:

```
 getProjResults = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('--------hit4')
    axios.all([
        axios.get(`/api/projects?search=${this.state.term}`),
        axios.get(`/words?ml=${this.state.term}`)
    ]).then(axios.spread(function(dbResponse, wApiResponse) {
        console.log("DB Info", dbResponse.data);
        console.log("Words API Info", wApiResponse.data)
        this.setState({
            answer1: '',
            answer2: dbResponse.data,
            answer3: wApiResponse.data
        })
    })
}
```

answer1 is for if the user searches by company, and is set in a different function.  the getProjResults function is invoked in the onClick handler on the search button.  Do I need to create a new function to tell it to search by the synonyms as well, or can I do that in this function?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you should be doing this on the backend so you only need to make a single call to your api.

You need to get synonyms from the words api first and then get listings for all the words.